# Specifying location.path in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use $location.path to do a redirect in angularjs.
I have the following config:

```
ngModule.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // Note: when adding a templateUrl, ensure that it's not a redirect but the full URL
        $stateProvider
            .state('logged-off', {
                url: '/logged_off',
                templateUrl: function () {
                    return '/partials/logged_off/';
                }
            });
   }]);
```

Then :

`$location.path('logged_off');` works fine, but I would like to refer to the state (so logged-off in this case) instead of the url. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it mandatory to use `$location`?

Have you tried [$state.go](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state)?

```
$state.go('logged_of');
```

Comment: I did try it, but I didn't put a condition based on the toState, so I was in an infinity loop :). Thanks